# How can I separate the arbitrary characters from a string object in java

Tags: java, string

How can I separate the arbitrary characters from a string object  in java? For example consider the following code and I want to separate arbitrary characters from that.

`String string = "My String";`.

in the above code, I want to get the `t` character from `string` object and then assign it in the `subString` object like the following :

`String subString = "t";`

Comment: Have a look at the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `string.charAt(index)`.
It is used to select the characters in the original string with the specified index.

```
String string = "My String";
char c = string.charAt(4);
System.out.println(c);
```

Output: `t`

Comment: Did you test your answer? What is return type of `charAt`? Hint: take a look at methods name.